# Generate output for a given Github Action

Tags: firebase, github, github-actions, firebase-hosting, cicd

I'm trying to get the output of a given github action, in this case: https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action

The thing is that there's no output from this action, and I was wondering how could I get the prints that the workflow itself did during that github action step.

[image: gh-action-deployment]

Comment: did you already seen this issue https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/145 ?

Comment: I saw the issues I actually made one myself
The question here is: Is there a way of generating an output by yourself like looking up any action print logs, as the one in the image

Comment: You can't extract an output through a workflow in a `uses` step without updating the action. However, you could eventually fork the action (or contribute to it) by adding the output you need there.

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd, I still have little experience with my own actions thats why i was asking. Good to know I cant extract when i use `uses`that was my question, thanks!